# Algolia: Tracking Clicks on redirects / redirecting searches to specific landing pages no click data

Tags: redirect, analytics, data-conversion, rules

My customer has a few redirect rules in place to redirect searches to specific landing pages.

However, they lose the click data on those searches with the redirect in place so they can't track whether the redirect is working well.

Searches like “cleanser”, “toner”, “serum” have all redirects setup and show with 0 clicks in analytics.

Is there a way to track clicks on redirects?

Customer has set up click & conversion events using
Devs told me we used the first guide https://www.algolia.com/doc/guides/building-search-ui/events/react/

Previous advice provided ( Algolia tech support ) That it's not possible to track within Algolia Analytics.

Is there any update on this advice? It's a semi frequent question, I've seen?

( Understand 3rd party add-ons an option )